# Timber - Twig post.content returns null can't create ACF Gutenberg blocks

Tags: plugins, templates

I'm using Timber for a Wordpress site and I'm trying to start and build Gutenberg blocks. The blocks work in the backend editor but I cant get them to work in the template. In fact nothing from the content box prints to the screen when I try use {{post.content}} as it just returns null.

How to get post.content to return the content?

WP - 5.8
Timber 1.18.0

template-block-test.php

```
<?php
/* Template Name: block test */


$context = Timber::get_context();


Timber::render( 'template-block-test.twig', $context );
```

template-block-test.twig

```
{%  extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Header to test file</h1>

{{post.content}} //returns null
<pre>
{{dump()}}
</pre>

{%  endblock %}
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'acf/init', 'acf_forty_it_block', 9 );
add_action( 'acf/init', 'acf_forty_it_block_settings', 10 );

function acf_forty_it_block() {

    // Check function exists.
    if( function_exists( 'acf_register_block_type' ) ) {

        // register a testimonial block.
        acf_register_block_type( array(
            'name'              => 'fortyblock',
            'title'             => __('Forty'),
            'description'       => __('Forty does a great job at been 60/40'),
            'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
            'category'          => 'design',
            'icon'              => 'format-gallery',
            'keywords'          => array( 'test', 'forty',  ),
              
        ) );
    }
}



function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block, $content = '', $is_preview = false ) {
    $context = Timber::context();

    $context['block'] = $block;
    
    

    $forty = array(
        'top_header' => get_field('forty_top_header'),
        'text' => get_field('forty_text'),
        'list_content' => get_field('forty_list_content'),
        'image' => get_field('forty_image'),
        'color' => get_field('forty_color'),
      );
      
      $context['forty'] = $sixtyForty;

      $context['is_preview'] = $is_preview;
    // Render the block.
    Timber::render( 'blocks/forty.twig', $context );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the current page object to the timber context using `timber_context` filter.
Something like this

```php
add_filter('timber_context', 'bt_timber_add_to_context');
function bt_timber_add_to_context ($context) {
    // add current page content
    $context['page'] = Timber::get_post();

    return $context;
}
```

That's how I added it in my custom timber theme.
Now when you want to get the page content you can do this

```
{{ page.content }}
```

This is availalbe only if you use `Timber::context()` in your `render`/`compile` methods.
Basically if you use `Timber::context()`, one of the object properties will be `page`

Comment: That worked, thank you for the quick response.